# Randomly write on ExternalFilesDir on Samsung Tab S8 devices fails

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage, saucelabs

Randomly I verify an issue on write in ExternalFilesDir on Samsung Tab S8 devices.

I have created a test app that write in this path:
*packageFolder/documents/files.txt*

To do that I followed this steps:

I create a documents folder inside externalsFilesDir

```
val documents = File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "documents")
val documentsMkdirResult = documents.mkdirs()
```

And this folder was correctly created, then

I try to create a folder named "testFolder" inside the documents one:

```
val fileFolder = File(documents, "testFolder")
val fileFolderResult = fileFolder.mkdirs()
```

and I create the readme.txt file:

```
val txtFile = File(documents, "readme.txt")
val result = txtFile.createNewFile()
```

but sometimes createNewFile fails with this exception:

```
17:20:35 W System.err : java.io.IOException: Permission denied
17:20:35 W System.err : at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
17:20:35 W System.err : at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
17:20:35 W System.err : at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
```

**When this issue happens the folder named "testFolder" neither the readme.txt are been created**

I test this issue on saucelabs on this devices:
Samsung Tab S8, S8 ultra and S8+.

I not verify the issue on my Samsung Tab s8

This is the entire test code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var resultText: TextView? = null

    private var resultButton: Button? = null

    private var resultAsString = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        resultText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultTest)
        resultButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.resultButton)
        resultButton!!.visibility = View.GONE
        Thread{
            startTest()
        }.start()
    }

    private fun startTest() {
        try {
            runOnUiThread{
                resultAsString += "\ngetExternalFilesDir..."
                resultText!!.text = resultAsString
            }

            val documents = File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "documents")

            val documentsMkdirResult = if(!documents.exists()){
                documents.mkdirs()
            }else{
                true
            }


            val fileFolder = File(documents, "testFolder")

            val fileFolderResult = if(!fileFolder.exists()) {
                fileFolder.mkdirs()
            }else{
                true
            }


            if(documentsMkdirResult) {
                val txtFile = File(documents, "readme.txt")
                val result = txtFile.createNewFile()
                runOnUiThread{
                    resultAsString += "\nTest performed successfully"
                    resultText!!.text = resultAsString
                }
            }else{
                runOnUiThread{
                    resultAsString += "\nDocuments Folder not exists"
                    resultText!!.text = resultAsString
                }
            }



        } catch (e: Exception) {
            runOnUiThread{
                resultAsString += "\n ${e.message}"
                resultText!!.text = resultAsString
                resultButton!!.text = "Error"
                resultButton!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

    }



    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
}
```

**minsdk 23
target and compile sdk 32**

[getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))
*Starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT, **no permissions are required to read or write** to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling application. To access paths belonging to other packages, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.*

Comment: `app that write in this path: packageFolder/documents/file/files.txt` Sorry but such a path does not exist. Its not a full path either.

Comment: `val txtFile = File(documents, "files.txt")` Should not that be: `val txtFile = File(fileFolder, "files.txt")` ?

Comment: You should only call mkdirs() if the folders dont exist yet. As mkdirs() will return false if the folders already exist.

Comment: Please rewrite your code to use if (!file.exists()) if ( !file.mkdirs()) return; Dont continue if a needed folder could not be forced.

Comment: `TAG,
                "getExternalStorageDirectory ` Well that is not getExternalFilesDir() !

Comment: @blackapps mkdirs return false if the folder already exists, why it should be cause of the  java.io.IOException: Permission denied on txtFile.createNewFile() ?

Comment: ?????? What is it that you wanna say?

Comment: @blackapps The crash happens on  this line of code --> txtFile.createNewFile(); 
If the documents folder already exist I don't understand why sometimes the createNewFile in that folder fails with exception..

Comment: @blackapps I edited the question, i did a mistake to write the paths . When the crash happens the folder named "file" neither the files.txt are been created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250190/discussion-between-aeroxr1-and-blackapps).

Comment: You still blindly call mkdirs(). I told you how you should use it instead. Please adapt your code. It makes no sense to me diving in the problem if you dont. And i will not chat.

Comment: You don't catch the issue. 
I call it in blindly way, but it is not the problem.. I edit the first post with the correct code, but this is an example app that reproduce the java.io.IOException: Permission denied  on Samsung Tab S8.

The issue is that when I try to create new files inside the documents folder created with this 2 method:             val documents = File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "documents") val documentsMkdirResult = documents.mkdirs() ; the app crashes on createNewFile method.

Comment: You are not checking the return value of mkdirs(). And if false then stop.

Comment: I edit the code and the crash is still happen only on the TAB S8. I know that some check are missing, is a POC app that reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same exact tablet model.
So, I solved it by forcing a delete directory, when the file/dir not found exception was raised, and then creating again the directory.

Strange, but it did not happen on S6, S7, Simulator and other samsung/Xiaomi devices.

Comment: do you have this issue on saucelabs or in "real" life ?

Comment: @aeroxr1 it was in "real" life.